# Apache beam read schema from pubsub

Tags: python, apache-beam

I am very new to beam and reading streaming data so I hope my question is not too trivial.

I am using the beam Python SDK to read data from PubSub before writing it into some other files. As the data I receive is always in the same format, I tried to make use of the [schema](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#schemas) feature to parse the data I receive from PubSub.

The data received is always a dictionary `name: "my_name", value: 42`, so my pipeline looks like this:

```py
import typing

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromPubSub


class MySchema(typing.NamedTuple):
    name: str
    value: int

with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
    pipeline | ReadFromPubSub(topic=<my_subscription>).with_output_types(MySchema)
```

However, I then get the error `apache_beam.typehints.decorators.TypeCheckError: Output type hint violation at ReadFromPubSub: expected <class '__main__.MassificationImage'>, got <class 'bytes'>`

It makes sense as PubSub naturally gets bytes: I can just parse the data into a dictionary and then it seems to work.

```py
with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
    (pipeline 
        | ReadFromPubSub(topic=<my_subscription>)
        | beam.Map(lambda x: json.loads(x.decode("utf8"))).with_output_types(MySchema)
```

It seems to work fine, but does not having to parse the data into a dictionary kind of defeat the purpose of the schema ? Is there any more straightforward way of doing this ?

Answer (score 1):

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#schemas describes purposes of Beam schemas. The assumption is that

> Often, the types of the records being processed have an obvious structure. Common Beam sources produce JSON, Avro, Protocol Buffer, or database row objects; all of these types have well defined structures ...

And the schema makes further transforms easier.

The confusion here is that Pub/Sub as a source doesn't provide structured data directly. Or at least the Beam IO for Pub/Sub reads bytes.

Pub/Sub does support schemas: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/schemas. You may create a new IO to merge the bytes-read and schema-parse.